# For an algorithm developed in MATLAB Simulink , how do I hide my implementation that is inside the algorithm (subsystem)?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, simulink

I have tried the following solutions:
1. Creating a sFunction of the sub-system (but I cannot go with that solution, because creating a sFunction mandates that the model is compiling)
2. Creating a masked system, right click and change "Read/Write Permission" setting to "NoReadWrite". But anyone can change "Read/Write Permission" setting back to Read/Write and browse through the sub-system.

Any way if we can stop user from re-changing the settings or some password protection, etc. will be of real help.

I really appreciate your suggestions/views on this. Thank you!!

Comment: What do you mean by _"creating a sFunction mandates that the model is compiling"_ ?

Comment: Sorry because of my unclear statement.
Well I meant, that if we have to create a sFunc, the model/subsystem has to be compiled first. 
For E.g. The model is error free. Only, I do not have the correct tunable values to be used in the algorithm, so I do not want to compile (by any unknown values), hence I cannot create the sFunct. Instead I can make a masked system (and hide contents somehow), and expose all tunable constants. The calibrators can tune the algorithm with correct values (w/o knowing the algorithm design).
Hope this clears what I am trying to say.
Thanks..

Comment: You can always have parameters in sfucn block for any constants that you're gong to change/tune

Comment: Yeah, I guess there is no other better way than creating an sFunction. Thanks POW..

Answer (score 1):

Well, creating an S-Function of the subsystem is normally the most straightforward way of protecting IP. As mentioned in the comments, it is not clear what you mean by "creating a sFunction mandates that the model is compiling". Surely, if your model doesn't compile, you have to address this first before?

An alternative is to use a protected model reference, but that requires using a referenced model, in combination with code generation (same as an S-Function), and you're obviously constrained by the model reference limitations. It requires a license of Simulink Coder. Have a look at the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/protecting-referenced-models.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can code your algorithm in a s-function , compile the s-function to mex file and then only deliver the  mex-file.

Mex mex(32 or 64) file can be used with s-function block in model, the block only requires file name not the actual code

Comment: You can also automatically generate an S-Function from an existing subsystem, and use the same technique, i.e. deliver only the generated `mex` file.